# How to check which classes are loaded in jboss7?

Tags: java, jboss7.x

I am using jboss-as-7 for my web application and I want to check which classes have been loaded after i started my jboss application server. How can i check this?

Thanks

Comment: Searching for this ? http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/docs/Server_Configuration_Guide/4/html/Inside_the_JBoss_Class_Loading_Architecture-Viewing_Classes_in_the_Loader_Repository.html

Comment: Why do you need this? What's the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: I am getting an error in my application..       java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: loader (instance of org/jboss/modules/ModuleClassLoader) previously initiated loading for a different type with name "org/apache/log4j/Priority"   for one servlet which is there in .ear. So i just want to check if it is loaded properly in jboss

Comment: What version of JBoss AS and are you including a log4j library in your deployment?

Comment: i am using jboss-7.1.0 and log4j is not there..

Answer (score 1):

You can enable the logging for the classloader.

Refer this link

[Enable logging for JBOSS class loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6690000/enable-logging-for-jboss-class-loading)

Comment: It is for jboss5.. is it same for jboss-as-7?