# Remote Access to EJB's on JBOSS AS7.1 from JBOSS 5.1

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss7.x, classloader, ejb-3.0, jboss5.x

I have an enterprise application delopyed on JBOSS 5.1. It needs to remotely access EJB's deployed on another instance of JBOSS AS 7.0+.
Now since AS 7.0+ remote access of EJB protocol has changed and there is a dependency on jboss-client.jar file contents for remote access.

Some of the classes inside jboss-client.jar from 7.0+ have the same structure as the libaries available in 5.1(Ex.: org.jboss.logging.Logger). However both the classes have different set of methods.

Invoking a remote EJB from 5.1 as follows

```
 final Hashtable jndiProperties = new Hashtable();
 jndiProperties.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES,"org.jboss.ejb.client.naming");
 context = new InitialContext(jndiProperties);

 final String appName = "my-ear";
 final String moduleName = "my-ejb-1.0";
 final String distinctName = "";
 final String beanName = "ServiceBean";         
 final String viewClassName = "org.test.Service";
// let's do the lookup
 Service service = (Service) context.lookup("ejb:" + appName + "/"
                + moduleName + "/" + distinctName + "/" + beanName + "!"
                + viewClassName + "?stateful");
```

leads to NoSuchMethodException for org.jboss.logging.Logger.getMessageLogger

This is because JBOSS 5.1 has a library called 'jboss-logging-spi.jar' which contains the exact same class(Logger) as above. hence the JVM tries to invoke getMessageLogger on Logger class defined in 'jboss-logging-spi.jar' instead of 'jboss-client.jar'.

Any ideas on how can i can enforce the JVM to look for the right class(Logger in jboss-client.jar)?

So far I tried this option:

- bundle the jar(jboss-client.jar) as part of enterprise application on 5.1.This did not work

  - remove the 'jboss-logging-spi.jar'. This stops the start of JBOSS server as this is referred in server startup
  - Use jboss-classloading.xml file. This did not yield the desired resut as well Link :http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-configuration/solving-jboss-5-classloading-issues

Any ideas on resolving this problem of invoking EJBs remotely hosted on JBOSS 7.0+ from application running on JBOSS 5.1?

Answer (score 0):

In order to fix the class version issue, the third option looks to be the right approach.

What I see from the link that you have posted, is that probably [you need](http://javadevtips.blogspot.com/2011/10/how-to-make-correct-classloading-using.html) to add to Classloading element the attribute:

```
parent-first="false"
```

> parent-first (true/false) -  the classloader should load at first
>   everything from your war/ear/jar and then  from parent(in case of
>   war/jar within ear it would mean ear, otherwise it's JBossAS)

Additionaly, there is a couple of tools that can be useful when you are dealing with Classloder configuration, enable jboss classloder [logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6690000/enable-logging-for-jboss-class-loading) and to use the [JMX Console](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/docs/Server_Configuration_Guide/4/html/Inside_the_JBoss_Class_Loading_Architecture-Viewing_Classes_in_the_Loader_Repository.html).

I hope this can help.